# SOLVED - Struggling to create a a specific Modal Popup for each item in a mapped array list when clicked - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mapping, react-hooks

I have a menu where I create a list of buttons for each file in async storage, however I'm struggling to find a way to make a "Confirm Delete" popup appear onLongPress.  I don't know how to create a base Modal Component that I can pass item specifics to within the map, so that when I long press on a specific file, a popup will appear to give me an option to delete the specific file that was pressed.

I have no idea what the correct approach is.  At this stage I don't even know how to get the modal visible.  What I've tried:

Here is my map:

```
{props.fileList.map((item) => {
    return(
         <TouchableOpacity 
               key={item.id} 
               style={styles.fileButton} 
               onLongPress={() => deletePopupHandler(item)} 
               onPress={() => loadFile(item)}>
                  <Text>
                      {item}
                  </Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
                )
                })}
```

my delete popup handler (i think this is where I'm making a mistake, I don't know how I can properly pass item info from a map to an onLongPress fucntion):

```
    const deletePopupHandler = (item) => {
        console.log('indeletepopophandler')
        deletePopupContent = <DeletePopup 
                                popupVisible={popupVisible} 
                                setPopupVisible={setPopupVisible}
                                item={item}
                            />
        setPopupVisible(true)
    }
```

my Delete Popup component (haven't bothered to write the yes button function yet as I can't get the modal to appear with item specifics):

```
        <Modal visible={props.popupVisible} transparent={true}>
            <View style={styles.popupContainer}>
                <View style={styles.popupWindow}>
                    <Text style={styles.message}>
                        Delete?
                    </Text>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonYes}><Text>Yes</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonNo} onPress={() => props.setPopupVisible(false)}><Text>No</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </Modal>
```

Then I just have the variable {deletePopupContent} within a  in the apps return function.

Thanks

**EDIT - Found a way around it, though answer below is better**
So I found a way for it to work if anyone else runs into the same thing.  I removed the Modal from the component and instead wrap a Modal around {deletePopupContent} instead.

So component changed to:

```
            <View style={styles.popupContainer}>
                <View style={styles.popupWindow}>
                    <Text style={styles.message}>
                        Delete?
                    </Text>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonYes}><Text>Yes</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonNo} onPress={() => props.setPopupVisible(false)}><Text>No</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
```

In my App return I have:

```
<Modal visible={popupVisible}>
   {deletePopupContent}
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DeletePopup has to be part of the DOM before it can show. Since you use visible={props.popupVisible} to control its visibility, you can add the popup to your main component. Does the Modal work at all?  You can set visible to true to verify.  In deletePopupHandler , you can save selected item to state. When user confirmed, you delete the saved item otherwise you reset the selected item to null.  Check the example i made here. https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-williamson-v7tug?file=/src/App.js

Comment: ahhhh nice thanks. I found a way around which I showed in my question edit by taking the modal outside of the component, I don't really know why it works. I was trying to find a way to pass the file name through a prop but I didn't think to use a separate state for it to keep track of what filename was selected. Thanks!